# ERROR: relation "public.databasechangeloglock" does not exist at character 22

Tags: postgresql

ERROR:  relation "public.databasechangeloglock" does not exist at character 22
2023-11-13 05:12:13.811 UTC [70] STATEMENT:  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public.databasechangeloglock

i am deploying my application in docker using jhipster generator code while try to connect data base in container not working getting above error but i am try to connect locally able to connect.